# Pointer to a record in OCaml

Tags: pointers, ocaml, binary-search-tree, record, imperative-programming

I am implementing binary search trees in OCaml, trying to use as much imperative programming as possible.

I have the following data type:

```
type tKey = Key of int;;

type tBST = Null | Pos of node ref
            and node = {mutable key : tKey; mutable left : tBST; mutable right : tBST};;
```

I am having trouble with this function:

```
let createNode k tree = 
    tree := Pos ({key = k; left = Null; right = Null});;

Error: This record expression is expected to have type node ref
       The field key does not belong to type ref
```

A binary search tree can be either Null (means empty tree) or a Pos. A tree Pos is a pointer to a node, and a node is a structure of a key and 2 other trees (left and right).

My main goal here is to have a tree that is modified after functions are over. Passing tree by reference so when createNode is over, the tBST I passed as parameter is modified.

Question: is actually possible to do what I am trying in OCaml? if so, how could I change my function createNode and/or data type to make this happen?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but you need to create the `Pos` node with a reference explicitly:

```
Pos (ref {key = k; (*...*)})
```

Whether what you are trying to do is recommended practice in a language like Ocaml is a different story, though.

Comment: Thank you sooo much. Exactly, I am well aware it would be way easier using recursive and pure code, which I already have implemented. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been answered. I would just like to add a side note: The use of `ref` seems superfluous in this case.

A value of type `tBST` is either `Null` or a mutable pointer. If it is `Null` it will remain `Null`. If it is non-`Null`, it will remain non-`Null`, but the actual pointer might change. That might well be what you intended, but I have my doubts. In particular, what `tBST` does not do, is to emulate C-style pointers (which are either `null` or really point somewhere). I suspect, though, that that was your intention.

The idiomatic way to emulate C-style pointers is to just use the built-in `option` type, like so:

```
type tBST = node option
```

A value of type `node option` is either `None` or `Some n`, where `n` is a pointer to a value of type `node`. You use `tBST` for mutable fields (of the record `node`), so you would effectively have mutable C-style pointers to nodes.

Comment: Mmmm thank you so much for the info kne, never heard about that before. That would make a lot of more sense regarding the Null case. However, I don't only want to emulate C-style pointers but to have a real functionality

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you probably had in mind:

```
type tree = node option ref
and node  = {
  mutable left: tree;
  mutable key: int;
  mutable right: tree;
};;

let t0 : tree = ref None;;
let t1 : tree = ref (Some { left = ref None; key = 1; right = ref None; }) ;;

let create_node key tree = 
  tree := Some { left = ref None; key; right = ref None; }
```

No need to have a separate type for `key` but you can if you want it, and with the latest OCaml there no runtime overhead for it.